# Can "this" refer to two items?

Tags: grammar

> In our hometown, walk into a supermarket and you are instantly
> confronted with a wealth of information and semiotic signals to guide
> your decision-making. **This** will be everything from recognisable brand
> names, product aisle descriptions, even simple colours (to signify the
> supermarket’s own brand, for example).

I think bolded "this" refers to information and semiotic signal. But then doesn't it have to be "these" to be correct in grammatically?

Answer (score 2):

"This" refers to "wealth".

... you are instantly confronted with a wealth *(of information and semiotic
signals)* to guide your decision-making. This will be everything from
recognisable brand names...

---

If you remove the word "wealth", you'll get:

"...you are instantly confronted with information and semiotic signals to guide your decision-making. **These** will be everything from recognisable brand names"